# Import text file into csv file

Tags: python, csv, text

I am new in Python and looking to change text data in csv data, where column contains id, sequence, createdAt, and createdBy?

**Text File**

```
[{"id":1,"sequence":14,"createdAt":"2021-03-04xx:x:x","createdBy":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}},

{"id":2,"sequence":14,"createdAt":"2021-03-04Txx:x:x","createdBy":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}},

{"id":3,"sequence":14,"createdAt":"2021-03-04Txx:x:x","createdBy":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}}]
```

Comment: How do you get your data? Can you share us some code where you create or import your data? We need to know where in the workflow (import/create data, edit it, save it, submit it) you encounter problems.

Comment: @Teresa Its a JSON data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input Data Set appears to be JSON structure
I'd recommend **csvkit** https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Specifically , module `in2csv` - very powerful

Alternatively - use pandas read_json - this will enable you load into a DataFrame